# how to count how many letters in my Junk in gmail?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, imaplib

I can list sub directories in my gmail.

```
import imaplib
user="xxxx"
password="yyyy"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
con.list()

#i ommit the info which contain code that is not properly formatted as code.
```

There are  6 directories Junk,Trash,Flagged,Sent,All,Important  ,now i want to count out how many letters in my Junk?

```
type,data=con.status('Junk','')   #can't run
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
con.select("[Gmail]/Spam") # for the label "Sent" use: "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
status, data = con.search(None, "ALL")
print len(data[0].split()) # prints the number of msgs in your Spam
```

Comment: the number you get is letters in all ,what i want is how many letters in my junk or in my sent mail.

Comment: >>> con.select("[Gmail]/Spam")
('NO', [b'[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail]/Spam (Failure)'])

Comment: @it_is_a_literature The `S` (in Spam) is capital

Comment: @it_is_a_literature you might get that when the folder is empty. After you do `con.login(user, password)` run `print con.list()` to see all the available labels

Comment: A puzzle still remain,why a string of chracters "&V4NXPpCuTvY-" can stand for my mailbox  "Junk"?

Comment: Did you have your gmail app on your mobile a few years back ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
>>> mail.login('aaa@bbb.com', 'ccc')
('OK', ['aaa@bbb.com authenticated (Success)'])
>>> mail.list()
('OK', [......, '(\\Junk \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/&bla-bla-bla-"', .....])
```

and then copy this string

```
"[Gmail]/&bla-bla-bla-"
```

into "select" method argument

```
>>> mail.select("[Gmail]/&bla-bla-bla-")
('OK', ['27'])
```

If i don't mistake '27' is a number of mails in junk mailbox

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself,cheer.

```
con.select("[Gmail]/&V4NXPpCuTvY-") #please look at the attatchment at the top,it is said that:  b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/&V4NXPpCuTvY-"'  .
```

Comment: cheers indeed!!! (this is per your account only - `"[Gmail]/&V4NXPpCuTvY-"` won't work on other accounts)